# C++ std::async vs async/await in C#

Tags: c#, c++, asynchronous, async-await

I'm wondering if the new c++ feature `std::async` is quite comparable to the two C# keywords async/await or not and if not why?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not really, assuming I'm reading [this std::async documentation](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/future/async.html) correctly.

C# 5's async/await feature involves a complex compiler transformation of the asynchronous method so that you can write code which looks pretty much synchronous, but has points of asynchrony. The compiler builds a state machine for you, creates appropriate callbacks etc.

EDIT: While I previously believed that `std::async` simply forced you to pass in a callback explicitly, it looks like it's even more primitive than that. Either way, I believe it's mostly/completely a *library* feature whereas C# 5's asynchronous methods are mostly a *language* feature with library support.

EDIT: As noted further in comments, it [looks like it's on its way for VC++](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/20/asynchronous-programming-in-c-using-resumable-functions-and-await.aspx)...

Comment: `std::async` has no continuations or completion callbacks.  All you can do is block while waiting for it to complete.  It is very primitive compared to the TPL.

Comment: But in C++ you can implement the equivalent of C# 5's await as a _library_ feature, using coroutines. Proof: [CppAwait](https://github.com/vmilea/CppAwait)

Comment: @valentin.milea: I don't have enough knowledge of C++ or Boost.Context to see how your code compares with `await`. I suspect it isn't *fully* equivalent, which isn't to say it isn't useful.

Comment: @Jon: In C# terms, there has been similar work using yield operator by [Tomas Petricek](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async.aspx), [Jeffrey Richter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546608.aspx). Regarding equivalence - there's less syntactic sugar but you get roughly the same benefits for code flow, exception handling. I'm sure C# certainly does some things better by building upon .NET TPL.

Comment: @ValentinMilea: Yes, because `yield` builds a state machine in a similar way - but again, it requires compiler support.

Comment: @JonSkeet: C# compiler supports semi-coroutines via yield, which can be done in [other ways](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/soc/coroutine/coroutine/implementation.html) in C/C++ (either use Duff's device to build a state machine, or switch between stacks as Boost.Context does)

Comment: @ValentinMilea: As I say, I'd need to look at the details more closely to compare them, but I'd be surprised if any library-only version had all the advantages of the language-supported version.

Comment: Following proof-of-concept shows that **exact syntax** of `await` feature can be emulated with help of Stackful Coroutines: [`await_emu`](https://github.com/panaseleus/await_emu)

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: I'm not seeing the function using `await` itself returning something like `Task<T>`... one example shows it returning `int`, which is very odd... how can it return an `int` immediately (which it needs to do to be asynchronous) if it hasn't actually completed yet?

Comment: "which is very odd" - it is extension which is not available to C#. Here, await can happen at arbitrary deep levels, without need to place `async`+`await` on each intermediate method. Check example output - it is real output which I copied from running that program.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: (Reordered comments for the sake of anyone looking.) That doesn't sound ideal to me. The way that asynchrony flows between method calls is one of the appealing aspects in the C# approach. If I call a function which returns int, I expect it to block until it has a result - how does it even flow in the C++ version? Again, I'm not saying this isn't useful - I'm just saying it's not really like-for-like. Making it easy to tell what's going to be asynchronous feels like a real advantage to me.

Comment: "Again, I'm not saying this isn't useful" - I understand your position, I just showing an example what can be done with stackful coroutines.
Here is side-by-side comparison: http://ideone.com/TEwwof - `await` syntax is exactly same, but `async` is a bit different - `asynchronous` should be placed at the place of call instead of signature.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk: I'd need to look in considerably more detail to work out what's going on here and what the pros and cons are. And the C++ templates etc does make this sort of thing a lot more feasible.

Comment: VC++ just got c# like await.. see this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/12/20/asynchronous-programming-in-c-using-resumable-functions-and-await.aspx

Answer (score 1):

CPPASYNC (provided in another answer) looks like what you are looking for. The "Async" part is easy and the performance looks good (likely better than the C# implementation). 
It's ugly b/c you need special "Await" wrappers around async callback calls. Some Boost networking is provided, and they're easy to make, but you can't just "Await" anything:
Async any method/function, 
Within an Async function, await either:
- An Async function
- An await wrapper (simple to make) around an asynchronous function (that takes a callback)

Comment: I'm really confused by this answer. I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: I think he meant [CppAwait](https://github.com/vmilea/CppAwait) gives something comparable to C#'s async/await, but you need to wrap preexisting async API to make it awaitable (like I did for part of Boost.Asio). Not the right place since question was about std::async.